# What does fireEvent.click() function return in react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am working with react testing library. I realized that fireEvent.click function seems to be returning a boolean value. What does this return value indicate? In which cases will the value be true, and in which cases will the value be false?

[image]

Comment: check this --> https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their code [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/main/src/fire-event.js#L7) you can see they're importing `fireEvent` from `@testing-library/dom` and looking at the code for this function [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/main/src/events.js#L5) you find the following:

```
function fireEvent(element, event) {
  return getConfig().eventWrapper(() => {
    if (!event) {
      throw new Error(
        `Unable to fire an event - please provide an event object.`,
      )
    }
    if (!element) {
      throw new Error(
        `Unable to fire a "${event.type}" event - please provide a DOM element.`,
      )
    }
    return element.dispatchEvent(event)
  })
}
```

So the return value is the same as that `dispatchEvent` function which according to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) from mdn is as follows:

"false if event is cancelable, and at least one of the event handlers which received event called Event.preventDefault(). Otherwise true."